# Add or Remove List Item Permissions Without a Workflow

Tags: 2010, permissions, spservices

I have a list in SharePoint 2010 that has custom SharePoint forms built for different situations depending on an approval process where each item is approved by two different people. Once the item is initially submitted, I need to be able to change the permissions on that specific item so the person who created it only has "Read" rights and cannot edit it (most likely in one of the PreSave functions). Additionally, if the level 1 approver requires the creator to make changes, I will need to have some way to do that depending on the choice the level 1 approver selects on his form.

Is any of this possible without using workflows? I was hoping SPServices would be a solution, but I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 2):

You can write an event receiver for your list that handles permissions of the item. You should use `ItemAdded` event receiver.

Some links event receivers:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms437502(v=office.14).aspx
2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms453149(v=office.14).aspx

and link about managing permissions programmatically:

3. [How to change programmatically privileges/permissions on SPListItem](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/28358/how-to-change-programmatically-privileges-permissions-on-splistitem)

Comment: Most excellent! I will check all of that out :) Thanks

Comment: Ended up using an extremely effective workflow. My concern was that the workflow would trigger other workflows in an endless loop, but I was able to work around that.